# removing a whitespace between two specific words

Tags: regex, uppercase, lowercase, removing-whitespace

I'm dealing with some census data that has been transcribed into a txt file. The fields are separated by spaces, however, rather than commas or tabs. Here are a few fields from a typical line, which will help illustrate my problem:

```
18A 1   239 18A Coffey Street     165    125 331 McLocklan      Donald     New York
```

Some of the fields are separated by multiple spaces, but some are separated by only one space. Some *fields* however, have more than one word in them (ex: New York), also separated by a single space.

I think I know how to do this by differentiating the single spaces between a lowercase letter and an uppercase letter versus the single spaces between two uppercase letters. I am still new to regex and am not sure how to do this however. Can anyone tell me how I can express the wish to replace a single space between a word/character group ending in a lowercase letter and a word/character group beginning with an uppercase letter with an underscore?

I think this would allow me to group things like Coffey_Street and New_York, without also connecting fields like 18A_Coffey. Any suggestions or advice would be most welcome. Thanks!

-Connor

Comment: Umm... are the fields actually fixed-width rather than delimited?

Comment: By the looks of the spacing of this CSV file, you're working with a fixed-width dump, like @AndrewMorton asked. You can easily tell this by showing more lines of output (3-4 should be fine), since we can quickly visually assess whether this is the case. In that case, the regex could be made much simpler with fewer edge cases causing formatting problems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I think they are fixed-width. These are text files from a census transcribing site: http://us-census.org/pub/usgenweb/census/ny/kings/1910/ed0082-pg001a.txt

I'm working in Text Wrangler with instructions from Dan Nguyen's The Bastard's Book of Regular Expressions (http://regex.bastardsbook.com/). For some reason though, some of the expressions that are supposed to work a certain way, just kind of aren't. I'm also playing around in Regexr.com and Rubular.com with similar results.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask whoever sent you the file to send it again with a better delimiter.  Adding an underscore between a lowercase and uppercase letter will not work in all cases.

That said, you can accomplish it with this command.

```
sed -r 's/([a-z]) ([A-Z])/\1_\2/g' file
```

Explanation

```
([a-z]) - match a lowercase character and group it
([A-Z]) - match an uppercase character and group it
the space in between - matches a space character
```

when `sed` finds a match to that pattern it replaces it like this

```
\1 - puts back the lowercase character
_ - puts an _ where the space was
\2 - puts back the uppercase character
```

Comment: +1, but do we know he's using sed?.. Maybe he doesn't know that he can do that in many regex environments (@OP look at substitutions [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/aI5jQ8))

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the demo. To be honest, I don't even know if I'm using sed. As I mentioned above, I'm just teaching myself, kind of groping my way through, seeing what works. I've always found that to be the best way to learn something - but I really appreciate forums like this for when I come up against something that I can't figure out! Thanks for your help!